# When I run “mvn install” of my module, it occurs error

Tags: java, maven, installation

My project is based on maven. I am about to run one of the sub-projects in a cluster project, but when I try to package my project (mvn package), the idea compiler reports an error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.4.2:check (spotless-check) on project flink-udf-robot: Execution spotless-check of goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.4.2:check failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: class com.google.googlejavaformat.java.RemoveUnusedImports (in unnamed module @0x42507640) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x42507640 -> [Help 1]

It seems that this problem is related to the JDK, but I am not sure what to do specifically. I am a newbie in programming and don't know much about environmental issues.

I encountered this problem when I was executing the `mvn clean->mvn install` step. The compiler used in my project is javac.

Comment: See https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/871 and https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/834

Answer (score -1):

**Check Maven Version:**
You can check your Maven version by running `mvn -version`. If needed, update Maven to the latest stable version.

**Check Dependencies:**
Verify that the dependencies specified in your

> pom.xml

file are correct and accessible. If a dependency is not found or if there's a version conflict, it can lead to build failures.

**Clean the Project:**
Run `mvn clean install`. This will clean the target directory and then run the install phase. Sometimes, artifacts from a previous build can cause issues.
**Run with Debug Mode:**
You can run Maven in debug mode to get more detailed information about the build process. Use `mvn install -X` to enable debug output.

Comment: thank you for response, my maven version is 3.6.3 and my java version is 21.0.1 in my system, i don't know whether these have conflict

Comment: in error can we read (goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.4.2:check failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: class ).  The InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that holds an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor. maybe if you can show the code , We can give you a restricted result , or we can solving the problem .

Answer (score -1):

I would like to comment and ask which JDK version you are using, but don't have enough "reputation" to comment. Anyways.

Which JDK version are you using? It looks like you are using a lower version of JDK than what's required for this maven plugin.

The `google-java-format 1.7` **requires** JDK 11 or higher. Can you try updating to JDK 11+?  This will allow you to use the latest version of `google-java-format` and `spotless-maven-plugin`.

Or you can downgrade your `spotless-maven-plugin` to `2.0.3` and `google-java-format` to `1.6`. This will make them compatible with JDK 8. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/main/plugin-maven/README.md#requirements

Or you can use a different formatter for your Java code, such as `eclipse-jdt`, `Palantir-java-format`, or `cleanthat`.

Comment: The error message comes from the module system, so unless Java 9 or 10 is used, Java 11 or higher already is used.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest `google-java-format` and `splotless-maven-plugin` may already fix this. The former is doing something it shouldn't do (access a class from a non-exported package); a newer version may have fixed that.

Comment: My JDK is 21.0.1 on my system,

Comment: My submodule is part of a large project. The google-java-format version under the pom file of this large project is 1.6. Do I need to change the google-java-format under this large project? Or I need to add a google-java-format configuration to the pom configuration under my submodule